# Exterior derivative for functions with values in a parallelizable manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, vector-bundles, connections

In Sharpe's text on Cartan geometry, [he explains in section 1.5 on page 52](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=Ytqs4xU5QKAC&pg=PA52&lpg=PA52&dq=exercise+5.2+sharpe+cartan&source=bl&ots=xrgrPQEann&sig=UBQ9u7LaRaNWHHs-mhlgPArNWUY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwik4-y7wtTMAhWKmZQKHdg-DTUQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=exercise%205.2%20sharpe%20cartan&f=false) how to define an exterior derivative for maps into a parallelizable manifold $N$. Let $f: M \to N$ be a smooth map, and $\theta: TN \to V$ a fibrewise linear isomorphism. This is obviously the same as a trivialization of the tangent bundle $TN \cong N \times V$. Now we can define an exterior derivative by
$$df := \theta \circ Tf.$$

For example, this is precisely how the Darboux derivative is defined if $N =G$ is a Lie group and $\theta: TG \to \mathfrak{g}$ is the Maurer-Cartan form (this generalizes and includes the case $G = \mathbb{R}$ for which we get the usual exterior derivative).

In general, the exterior derivative depends on the chosen trivialization $\theta: TN \to V$. For instance, given a map $\tau: N \to \text{GL}(V)$, we have another trivialization $\tau . \theta: TN \to V$ obtained by twisting by $\tau$. In general $d f = \theta \circ Tf$ will give a different result than $$d_\tau f := (\tau . \theta) \circ Tf.$$ For instance, given $v_x \in TM$ we have
$$(d f)(v_x) := \theta(Tf(v_x)),$$
$$(d_\tau f)(v_x) := \tau(f(x)) . \theta(Tf(v_x)).$$ 
Now this all makes sense to me, but then Sharpe says that

> "the exterior derivative computed relative to the trivialization
>   $\theta$ is the same as that computed relative to the trivialization
>   $\tau.\theta$ if and only if $\tau$ is constant."

Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but I don't see how we could have $d_\tau f= d f$ unless $\tau(x) = \text{id}_V$.

I have a feeling that this is an error, but I am not sure what Sharpe meant to write. I haven't been able to find errata for the text. I showed this to a few other grad students and they weren't sure what to make of it either.

Comment: Just asking: Are you sure that "twisting by $\tau"$ doesn't refer to $\tau\theta\tau^{-1}$...?

Comment: No unfortunately it says that for $w_y \in TN$ we have $(\tau.\theta)(w_y) = \tau(y)\theta(w_y)$.  Even if that were the case, I'm not sure how that would help, since $TN$ doesn't come equipped with a group action by $GL(V)$.

Comment: [Here](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=Ytqs4xU5QKAC&pg=PA52&lpg=PA52&dq=exercise+5.2+sharpe+cartan&source=bl&ots=xrgrPQEann&sig=UBQ9u7LaRaNWHHs-mhlgPArNWUY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwik4-y7wtTMAhWKmZQKHdg-DTUQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=exercise%205.2%20sharpe%20cartan&f=false) is the relevant part of the textbook, by the way.